# Prevent Electrical Wires from Cutting/Tearing in Ceiling Light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling, wire

I installed a Recessed Ceiling Light. The Manufacturer Halo Eaton built Silver Metal Mounting Rack with Very Sharp Inner Edges. Wires loop through the center sharp edge .

So when installing or removing a ceiling light, it may cut/tear, and spark. (it happened to previous customer)

Sometimes ceiling light gets stuck, electrical bundle wires in tight space (pressing against the sharp edges) Many different factors.

1) Do you recommend any solution to prevent wires from cutting/tearing, in ceiling lights?

2) Is it Okay to place Polypropylene Spiral Wrap to Prevent it from tearing? Is Polypropylene spiral safe to withstand high temperature like electrical tape?

**Proposed Solution:**

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-4-in-and-1-2-in-Spiral-Wrap-Assorted-Clear-FSP-AST2/202905456

**Halo Ceiling Light: BLD6089SWHR**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Product Reference:**

https://www.eaton.com/flash/electrical/connectedlighting/products/halo-home/smart-surface-mount-downlight/

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-BLD-6-in-White-Selectable-CCT-2700K-5000K-Integrated-LED-Recessed-Ceiling-Mount-Light-Trim-Title-20-Compliant-BLD6089SWHR/305501117

Comment: The first Product Reference: link is broken. the  first photo you posted is from home depot. Once you install the light there should be no movement of the wires  and they should all be tucked up into the space above the bracket so the insulation should be fine.

Comment: I was saying that the spiral wrap, Or anything else was not necessary. Once the wires are tucked into the cavity they are perfectly safe. But if it makes you feel better then it can’t do any harm.

Comment: what happens is we have apartment tenants who need to pull them out, to change the color spectrum 3000-5000k, etc

Comment: **Do not tell your tenants that the lights have the ability to be changed**. Pick the Kelvin you want and leave it at that.

Comment: Tell them, **in the lease**, ( *for any electrical changes* ) that if they want it changed they need to **contact you***.